# laravel routes undefined even when route is defined,

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code in my controller.

```
public function courierUpdate(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'current_location' => 'required',
        ]);
        $courierInfoUpdate =CourierInfo::findOrFail($id);
        $courierInfoUpdate->current_location = $request->current_location;
        
        $courierInfoUpdate->save();
        $notify[] = ['success', 'Courier location info has been updated'];
        return back()->withNotify($notify);
    }
```

I have form that would be used to update the shipping details;

```
<div class="row mb-30">
                <div class="col-lg-12 mt-2">
                    <div class="card border--dark">
                        <h5 class="card-header bg--dark">@lang('Courier Location')</h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form action="{{route('courier.Update')}}" method="POST">
                                    @csrf
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="current_location" class="form-control-label font-weight-bold">@lang('Current Location')</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="current_location" value="{{__($courierInfo->current_location)}}" required="">
                                        </div>
                
                                        
                
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-paper-plane"></i>@lang('Update')</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have also added the route in web.php

```
Route::post('/courier-Update','App\Http\Controllers\CourierSettingController@courierUpdate')->name('courier.Update');
```

But I get this eror when I run the page;

```
Route [courier.Update] not defined. (View: /home/somename/example.com/core/resources/views/admin/courier/details.blade.php)
```

When have cleared the route cache;

```
Route::get('/clear', function(){
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
});
```

But i still get the error message;

When I check the generated route paths using this code;

```
Route::get('routes', function () {
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

    echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='10%'><h4>HTTP Method</h4></td>";
    echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Route</h4></td>";
    echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Name</h4></td>";
    echo "<td width='70%'><h4>Corresponding Action</h4></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $value->methods()[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value->uri() . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value->getName() . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value->getActionName() . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
});
```

I get thisline indictating that the that route exist;

```
POST    admin/courier-Update    admin.courier.Update    App\Http\Controllers\Admin\App\Http\Controllers\CourierSettingController@courierUpdate
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: If you are in **laravel 7** try changing to this `Route::post('/courier-Update', 'CourierSettingController@courierUpdate');` If **Laravel 8** use instead `Route::post('/courier-Update', [CourierSettingController::class, 'courierUpdate']);`

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
route('courier.Update')
```

with

```
route('admin.courier.Update')
```

Since that's the full name of your route.

You probably declared your route inside a route group that adds the `admin.` prefix to the name of your route.

Comment: Hi @pros, I'm glad I was helpful! If the answer is correct than you can mark it as the accepted answer :)